# How to enable CAxxxx warnings?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, coding-style, warnings, visual-studio-2017

How can I enable code style warnings like [`CA1002: Do not expose generic lists`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182142.aspx) (or any other "Code Analysis for Managed Code Warnings")?

Part of the link is:

> **When to Suppress Warnings**
>
> Do not suppress a warning from this rule unless the assembly that
>   raises this warning is not meant to be a reusable library. For
>   example, it would be safe to suppress this warning in a performance
>   tuned application where a performance benefit was gained from the use
>   of generic lists.

This let me think, the compiler should show this warnings by some way.

I tried this code (Which seems to be a reason for CA1002 according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt?rq=1)):

```
public FooList : List<Foo>
{
}
```

It compiled fine without a warning. My warning level per project is already at max level 4:

[image: Warning Level]

So how can I enable the warnings?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547175.aspx

Comment: @BJMyers thank you. That is exactly what I needed. Seems like I searched for the wrong keywords. Consider to turn your comment into an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code Analysis warnings are separate from compiler warnings, and are enabled on the "Code Analysis" tab in project properties.

[image: Code Analysis tab on the project properties page]

Detailed instructions from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547175.aspx):

> 1. In **Solution Explorer**, right-click the project, and then click
>      **Properties**.
> 2. In the properties dialog box for the project, click **Code
>      Analysis**.
> 3. Specify the build type in **Configuration** and the target
>      platform in **Platform**.
> 4. To enable or disable automatic code analysis,
>      select or clear the **Enable Code Analysis on Build** check box.